# simple Spring AOP, but Aspect won't be triggered

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, aspect

I am trying to Practice Spring AOP. The Problem is, My program is not what I expect.

It should Look something like this when Aspect works.

```
Sep 27, 2020 1:11:11 PM aspects.LoggingAspect log
INFO: Method will execute
Sep 27, 2020 1:11:11 PM com.cms.services.CommentService publishComment
INFO: Publishing comment:Demo comment
Sep 27, 2020 1:11:11 PM aspects.LoggingAspect log
INFO: Method executed
```

However, It doesnt' log. Like Aspects haven't work at all.

```java
com.cms.services.CommentService publishComment
INFO: Publishing Comment: Demo Comment
```

**Main.java** executes overall code Using Instance spring Spring Context
and also uses **CommentService.java**.

**CommentService.java** is nothing but of printing one lined log.
It is placed under *services* package.

Then there is **LoggingAspect.java** For Aspect Programming.

Finally, **CommentConfig.java** is for configuring EnableAspectJAutoProxy and registering Beans for Aspect class.

Here is my code.

**Main.java**

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var c = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(CommentConfig.class);
        var service = c.getBean(CommentService.class);

        Comment comment = new Comment();
        comment.setText("Demo Comment");
        comment.setAuthor("Natasha");

        service.publishComment(comment);
    }
}
```

**CommentService.java**

```java
@Service
public class CommentService {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CommentService.class.getName());
    public void publishComment(Comment comment) {
        logger.info("Publishing Comment: " + comment.getText());
    }
}
```

**LoggingAspect.java**

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {

    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class.getName());

    @Around("execution(* services.*.*(..))")
    public void log(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println("method will execute");
            logger.info("Method will execute");
            joinPoint.proceed();
            logger.info("Method has executed");
        System.out.println("method has executed");
    }
}
```

**CommentConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.cms"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class CommentConfig {
    @Bean
    public LoggingAspect aspect() {
        return new LoggingAspect();
    }
}
```

Also, this is my dependency.

```xml
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aspects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-aop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.24</version>
        </dependency>
```

My Package Name

```
├─src
│  ├─main
│  │  ├─java
│  │  │  └─com
│  │  │      └─cms
│  │  │          │  Main.java
│  │  │          │
│  │  │          ├─aspect
│  │  │          │      LoggingAspect.java
│  │  │          │
│  │  │          ├─config
│  │  │          │      CommentConfig.java
│  │  │          │
│  │  │          ├─model
│  │  │          │      Comment.java
│  │  │          │
│  │  │          ├─proxies
│  │  │          │      CommentNotificationProxy.java
│  │  │          │      CommentPushNotificationProxyImpl.java
│  │  │          │      EmailCommentNotificationProxyImpl.java
│  │  │          │
│  │  │          ├─repositories
│  │  │          │      CommentRepository.java
│  │  │          │      DBCommentRepositoryImpl.java
│  │  │          │
│  │  │          └─services
│  │  │                  CommentService.java
│  │  │
│  │  └─resources
```

Can't figure out what is missing...

---

**Problem Solved.**
The Problem was indeed Because of I omitted the Full package name in the `@Around` Annotation.
Below code makes what I expected in the beginning.
**LoggingAspect.java**

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggingAspect {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoggingAspect.class.getName());

    @Around("execution(* com.cms.services.*.*(..))")    // this is where I missed.
    public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        String methodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
        Object arguments[] = joinPoint.getArgs();

        logger.info("Method " + methodName + " with Parameters " +
                Arrays.asList(arguments) + " will execute");
        Object returnedByMethod = joinPoint.proceed();
        logger.info("Method executed and returned " + returnedByMethod);
        return returnedByMethod;
    }
}
```

For those who are struggling like me, below documentation will help.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.0.x/reference/aop.html

It is about the The **AspectJ pointcut expression**.

Comment: What do you think `execution(* services.*.*(..))` should match?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn [how to ask a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thank you. You already provided important information, but did not walk the last two metres, adding the package names to all of the posted classes. More accurately, you deleted them and with them the most crucial information to disentangle this puzzle. Was that worth saving a couple lines of code? Now, everybody has to make educated guesses about the problem's root cause.

Comment: @kriegaex I am so sorry.  I didn't think the problem is related to the package. So I omitted the information.
Though, I should have give the package/filetree information anyways, if it was important or not.
I will keep this in mind when asking questions and be aware to give full information. Thank you for the advice sir.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis
I was expecting 
"When the method is called, call the Aspect. And that the pointcut should be in the service package."
Now I know from the comments and answers, the problem was the usage of @Around and @Within.

I should have written the full path `com.cms.service` instead of `service` when using @Around Annotation.

Answer (score 1):

### Within

Try with simple modification on **LoggingAspect**. **within** matches any join point within classes in packages containing "services".

```
@Around("within(*..services..*)")
public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("method will execute");
    logger.info("Method will execute");
    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
    logger.info("Method has executed");
    System.out.println("method has executed");
    return proceed;
}
```

### Around

**execution** specifically matches method executions of methods defined in classes within the "services" package. You have to specify full package for this. Follow the below code in your case. Your service method should be inside this package **com.cms.services**

```
@Around("execution(* com.cms.services.*.*(..))")
public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("method will execute");
    logger.info("Method will execute");
    Object proceed = joinPoint.proceed();
    logger.info("Method has executed");
    System.out.println("method has executed");
    return proceed;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. After Reading this answer, I immediately looked for the `@Around` and `@Within` Annotations. I was wrongly using it by NOT specifying the full package name for this. After specifing the full package name in the `@Around`, it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried including the path of your service?

@Around("execution(* **com.cms.services.CommentService**.*(..))")

Comment: No sir. After your comment, I tried to include the full package name as you mentioned. And it worked.

Answer (score 1):

My educated guess - but still just a guess - is, concluding from what little information I have and hoping that you did not just make up fake package names but forgot to edit them consistently:

```java
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.cms"})
```

The above means that no components outside of this base package will be found. But your pointcut says:

```java
@Around("execution(* services.*.*(..))")
```

If your service really is in that package, it will never be registered as a Spring component and therefore also never be intercepted by the aspect, even if the aspect happens to be in package `com.cms`. But it might just as well be the other way around, the aspect not being registered as a component if it is is another package.

Comment: Sorry for not giving the explicit path of the files. It is my fault for you to have the educated guess...

The problem was indeed about the package path as you mentioned below.

The pointcut was not being registered because I didn't explicitly gave the full package name in the `@Around` Code.

When I changed the 
`@Around(execution(* services.*.*(..)))` to `@Around("execution(* com.cms.services.*.*(..))")`, the result was indeed what I expected. Thank you.